# Vim + omnicppcomplete enum completion

Tags: c, vim, ctags, omnicppcomplete

Is it possible to make vim autocomplete from enum? 
Completion of structs works fine but enum completion doesn't work 
I have this code in C for example  :

```
enum {foo0, foo1, foo2} MyEnum;

MyEnum = (C^X) (C^O)
//or 
if (MyEnum == (C^X)(C^O))
```

I have all tags generated by this command:

```
ctags  --c++-kinds=+p --fields=+iaS --extra=+q main.c
```

and tags file contains IMO right information:

```
MyEnum  main.c  /^enum { foo0 , foo1, foo2 } MyEnum;$/;"    v   typeref:enum:__anon1
foo0    main.c  /^enum { foo0 , foo1, foo2 } MyEnum;$/;"    e   enum:__anon1    file:
foo1    main.c  /^enum { foo0 , foo1, foo2 } MyEnum;$/;"    e   enum:__anon1    file:
foo2    main.c  /^enum { foo0 , foo1, foo2 } MyEnum;$/;"    e   enum:__anon1    file:
```

Thanks for help and I'm sorry for my English

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use `omnicppcomplete` for about two years, and, as far as I know, it can't complete enums.

To get perfect C/C++/Objective-C code completion, i would recommend you to try [Clang Complete](http://goo.gl/hu0tA). And check out my [another answer](http://goo.gl/R6zZd) regarding to this.